# как удалить дублирующиеся объекты в массиве?

Tags: javascript

Мне надо удалить все дублирующиеся объекты в массиве так, чтобы остались только оригиналы объектов без дубликатов в массиве, желательно функцией.

```js
var arr = [{z:12, c:11}, {z:16, c:15}, {z:12, c:11}, {z:4, c:9}, {z:3, c:14}, {z:3, c:14}, {z:3, c:14}, {z:14, c:2}, {z:0, c:2}, {z:19, c:17}, {z:14, c:2}, {z:4, c:0}, {z:14, c:2}]; //а вообще, в этом массиве может быть сколько угодно подобных объектов, хоть 500, хоть 0, в большинстве своём с разными цифрами, но они могут повторяться где угодно, и мне нужно уничтожить все объекты-дубликаты в нём.
function deldub(ar) { //ar - массив. Функция будет удалять дубликаты в вписанном в неё массиве и глобально видоизменять его переменную.
   //лично я объявляю глобальные переменные через window. А вообще, эта функция должна глобально видооизменить массив
}
deldub(arr); //к примеру, сейчас она должна сделать window.arr = [{z:12, c:11}, {z:16, c:15}, {z:4, c:9}, {z:3, c:14}, {z:14, c:2}, {z:0, c:2}, {z:19, c:17}, {z:4, c:0}]; без пустых ячеек массива. Можно наверн объявить этот массив по другому, но главное, чтобы сам массив глобально изменился так, чтобы в нём не осталось дубликатов и пустых ячеек.
```

Я пытался через двойной цикл `for` и `.splice()` это решить, но у меня не получилось. Как я уже и писал в коде, этот массив может быть абсолютно с любыми цифрами `z` и `c` в объектах и с любым кол-вом объектов. Всем тем, кто сможет помочь решить эту проблему, заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В англоязычной версии есть краткое решение

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20339466/how-to-remove-duplicates-from-a-two-dimensional-array/#20339811

```
let result = arr.map(JSON.stringify).filter((e,i,a) => i === a.indexOf(e)).map(JSON.parse)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Варианты с `JSON.stringify` не будут работать, если свойства объекта и значения одинаковые, но в разном порядке. К примеру `{z:6,c:0}` и `{c:0,z:6}` оба попадут в  результат. Этот вариант делает глубокое сравнение объектов и исключает такое поведение.

```js
var arr = [{z:6,c:0}, {c:0,z:6}, {z:12, c:11}, {z:16, c:15}, {z:12, c:11}, {z:4, c:9}, {z:3, c:14}, {z:3, c:14}, {z:3, c:14}, {z:14, c:2}, {z:0, c:2}, {z:19, c:17}, {z:14, c:2}, {z:4, c:0}, {z:14, c:2}]; 


function sort(m){
  for(var i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
    for(var j = i+1; j < m.length; j++)
      if(m[j] && m[i] && isEqual(m[i],m[j])) delete m[j];
      
  arr = m.filter(e=>e)
  return arr
}   
console.log(sort(arr))

function isEqual(object1, object2) {
  const props1 = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object1);
  const props2 = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object2);

  if (props1.length !== props2.length) {
    return false;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < props1.length; i += 1) {
    const prop = props1[i];
    const bothAreObjects = typeof(object1[prop]) === 'object' && typeof(object2[prop]) === 'object';

    if ((!bothAreObjects && (object1[prop] !== object2[prop])) ||
      (bothAreObjects && !isEqual(object1[prop], object2[prop]))) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Используя [reduce](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods#reduce-reduceright):

```js
var arr = [
  {z:12, c:11}, {z:16, c:15}, {z:12, c:11}, {z:4, c:9}, {z:3, c:14}, 
  {z:3, c:14}, {z:3, c:14}, {z:14, c:2}, {z:0, c:2}, {z:3, c:14},
  {z:19, c:17}, {z:14, c:2}, {z:4, c:0}, {z:14, c:2}, {z:3, c:14},
];

function deldub(ar) {
  return ar.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    // использование JSON.stringify позволяет сравнивать любые объекты, без привязки к свойствам
    return acc.find(item => JSON.stringify(item) === JSON.stringify(cur)) ? acc : acc.concat([cur]);
    // просто сравнивая свойства всё ещё работает:
    // return acc.find(item => item.z === cur.z && item.c === cur.c) ? acc : acc.concat([cur]);
  }, []);
  // сокращение банально "обрезая" имена
  // return ar.reduce((a,c)=>a.find(i=>i.z===c.z&&i.c===c.c)?a:a.concat([c]),[]);
}

console.log( deldub(arr) );
```